# Laravel SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1091 Can't DROP FOREIGN KEY `services_department_id_foreign`; check that it exists

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Although the key exists, Laravel cannot find it and remove it in the migration and it errors out with the following message:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1091 Can't DROP FOREIGN KEY `services_department_id_foreign`; check that it exists (SQL: alter table `services` drop foreign key `services_department_id_foreign`

Here is the migration

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class AddPricingVersionIdToUniqueIndexForServices extends Migration
{
    const TABLE = 'services';
    const PRICING_VERSION_COL = 'pricing_version_id';

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        if (Schema::hasTable(self::TABLE) and Schema::hasColumn(self::TABLE, self::PRICING_VERSION_COL)) {
            Schema::table(self::TABLE, function (Blueprint $table) {
                // need to drop foreign keys first
                $table->dropForeign(['department_id']);
                $table->dropForeign(['pricing_version_id']);
                $table->dropForeign(['tenant_id']);
                $table->dropUnique('services_tenant_id_department_id_name_unique');
                $table->unique(['tenant_id', 'department_id', 'name', self::PRICING_VERSION_COL]);
                // put back foreign keys
            });
        }
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        // if (Schema::hasTable(self::TABLE) and Schema::hasColumn(self::TABLE, self::PRICING_VERSION_COL)) {
        //     Schema::table(self::TABLE, function (Blueprint $table) {
        //         $table->dropUnique('services_tenant_id_department_id_name_unique');
        //         $table->unique(['tenant_id', 'department_id', 'name', self::PRICING_VERSION_COL]);
        //     });
        // }
    }
}
```

Here is the database schema currently

[image: database schema in table plus db editor]

Here are screenshots with related entities and their schemas:

departments
[image: departments schema]
tenants
[image: tenants schema]

pricing versions
[image: pricing_versions schema]

It's strange because the foreign keys exist but it's not finding the columns. I even tried using the exact index names but that did not work either.

I'm using Laravel version 8 with a MySQL Databse.

Comment: A foreign key index is not a standard index, it has additional constraints (i.e. values in the index must exist in a column of another table). It's not clear from your screenshot if `services_department_id_foreign` has any such constraints (other than the name) so double check to make sure the constraint is correctly defined on the table

Comment: @apokryfos are there other screenshots I could provide to add more specific context?

Comment: @apokryfos I added the related schema screenshots

Comment: That's not what I was saying. I was saying that on the table `services` you have an **index** called `services_department_id_foreign` but it's not clear if that index includes a foreign key constraint. If you do `SHOW CREATE TABLE services` check whether the `services_department_id_foreign` is a foreign key. It should look like: `CONSTRAINT services_department_id_foreign FOREIN KEY (this column) REFERENCES other_table (other_table_column)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out for some reason the `foreign()` method from laravel wasn't creating an index for the `tenant_id` column when it created the foreign key. The migration was passing, but not creating that index.

Therefore when I tried to remove the unique constraint that included `tenant_id`, it didn't exist. By adding the index manually in a migration, and following up with adding it as a foreign key/removing the unique constraint it worked.

Here is the migration used to add a tenant id

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use App\Utils\IndexUtil;

class AddIndexForTenantIdOnServices extends Migration
{

    const INDEX_NAME = 'tenant_idx';
    const TABLE = 'services';
    const TENANT_COL = 'tenant_id';

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        if (
            Schema::hasTable(self::TABLE) && Schema::hasColumn(self::TABLE, self::TENANT_COL)
            &&  !IndexUtil::indexExists(self::INDEX_NAME, self::TABLE)
        ) {
            Schema::table(self::TABLE, function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->index(self::TENANT_COL, self::INDEX_NAME);
            });
        }
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        if (
            Schema::hasTable(self::TABLE) && Schema::hasColumn(self::TABLE, self::TENANT_COL)
            &&  IndexUtil::indexExists(self::INDEX_NAME, self::TABLE)
        ) {
            Schema::table(self::TABLE, function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->dropIndex(self::INDEX_NAME);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Also created a util to check if an index exists, which is not natively supported in Laravel at this time.

```
<?php

namespace App\Utils;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class IndexUtil
{

    /**
     * Check if an index exists on a table using the Doctrine Schema Manager
     * Laravel does not have a built-in way to check if an index exists
     *
     * @param string $indexName
     * @param string $tableName
     * @return bool
     */
    public static function indexExists(string $indexName, string $tableName): bool
    {
        $sm = Schema::getConnection()->getDoctrineSchemaManager();
        $indexesFound = $sm->listTableIndexes($tableName);

        return array_key_exists($indexName, $indexesFound);
    }
}
```